# How to add a line break using d3.js text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, text

I am trying to add text to a treemap I am creating, I want it to go like this

```
Test name
Item Count: 402
```

However it prints

```
Test name Item Count: 402
```

my code is this

```
cells.append("text")
                  .attr("x", d => x(d.x0 + 5) )
                  .attr("y", d => y(d.y0 + 20) )
                  .style("font", "13px sans-serif")
                  .text(d => d.data.name + "  \n Item Count: " + d.data.itemCount)
                  .attr("fill", "black")
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible in native d3 alone, because your new line character won't be recognized in svg.

To set something like this up automatically you'll have to use something like https://d3-annotation.susielu.com/ and set up the appropriate `bgPadding` property; this involves setting up a new array, customizing its relevant properties to match your underlying data, and formatting the annotation appearance.

Otherwise (and likely a much simpler solution than jumping into d3-annotation without the necessity of its other functions) you can append an extra text element for each of your cells, thus having one element displaying data name, and another displaying the item count. The second one of these would be offset by a certain number from the initial value of 20 (in the example below, I simply added 10px to it):

```js
cells.append("text")
                  .attr("x", d => x(d.x0 + 5) )
                  .attr("y", d => y(d.y0 + 20) )
                  .style("font", "13px sans-serif")
                  .text(d => d.data.name )
                  .attr("fill", "black")
                  
cells.append("text")
                  .attr("x", d => x(d.x0 + 5) )
                  .attr("y", d => y(d.y0 + 30) ) //note each of these is 10px lower
                  .style("font", "13px sans-serif")
                  .text(d => Item Count: " + d.data.itemCount)
                  .attr("fill", "black")
```